# Panning problems with Cocoa NSScrollView

Tags: cocoa, nsscrollview, nsimageview

Im using Xcode to make an application that has a NSImageView that I have made into an NSScrollView (I think) by means of selecting it in my .xib, going to the editor menu in Xcode then embedded in > scrollView.

I have an image in my NSScrollView that is larger than the window it is opened in, I can scroll using the scroll bars fine and have even turned on the `autoscroll:` function in my `mouseDragged:` method.

I would like to be able to simply pan around the image without touching the edges of the screen using `mouseDragged:`. So far my code for `mouseDragged:` in my panning.m(subclass of NSImageView) is such:

```
-(void)mouseDragged:(NSEvent *)theEvent{
   NSPoint p = [theEvent locationInWindow];
   [self scrollRectToVisible:NSMakeRect(p.x - self.visibleRect.origin.x, p.y - self.visibleRect.origin.y, self.visibleRect.size.width, self.visibleRect.size.height)];
   [self autoscroll:theEvent];
}
```

This works to some degree, however there is a lot of jittering. Maybe because I am not restricting the bounds?

I was wondering if I am on the right track or is there a better/more efficient way.

Any help is appreciated.

Cheers.

Comment: `UI...` is iOS and `NS...` is OS X.  Which is it?

Comment: `CGRectMake` should be `NSMakeRect`...